# which termux package provides the "mount" command?

Tags: installation, mount, terminal, termux

i try to install "mount" with apt, but i can't locate it, or a package that contains "mount".

i've tried:

- just to run mount:

  > no command 'mount' found
- apt update && apt upgrade
- apt install mount busybox toybox

  > busybox is already the latest versuib; mount and toybox do not exist.
- apt -s mount

  > option not understood
- apt search mount

  > proot ...
- apt install proot
- mount

  > not found...
- google, locate mount, ls -lR. GOT YOU

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mount command is part of the util-linux package.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Util-linux

Try `apt install util-linux`

Comment: Doesn't look like it's the case for Termux: `dpkg -L util-linux | grep mount` gives nothing.

Comment: Might have to build it. https://github.com/termux/termux-packages/tree/master/packages/util-linux

Comment: `libmount` is disabled in Termux's `util-linux` package. `mount` and `umount` are shell scripts which call same binaries from `/system/bin`.

Answer (score 4):

Either type

```
/system/bin/mount
```

manually or create a shortcut by

```
ln -s /system/bin/mount $PREFIX/bin/mount
```

so that you can access it more easily later.

Don't bother with `toolbox` or `toybox`. Whichever contains the mount command will be symlinked to by `/system/bin/mount`.

Answer (score 1):

While `which mount` yields nix, any of the following should produce output in Termux on Android, Chromebook and Fire OS.

`/system/bin/toybox mount`

`/system/bin/toolbox mount`

`/system/bin/mount`

[image]